# How to search for a 'text' or 'number' in a csv file with Python AND if exists print only first and second column values to a new csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to do the following using Python.

```
Step-1: Read a specific third column on a csv file using Python.
Step-2: Create a list with values got from step-1
Step-3: Take the value of index[0], search in csv file, if present print the values of column 1 and 2 only to a new csv file(There are 6 columns). If Not presents just ignore and goto next search.
```

**file1.csv:**

```
Country,Location,number,letter,name,pup-name,null
a,ab,1,qw,abcd,test1,3
b,cd,1,df,efgh,test2,4
c,ef,2,er,fgh,test3,5
d,gh,3,sd,sds,test4,
e,ij,5,we,sdrt,test5,
f,kl,6,sc,asdf,test6,
g,mn,7,df,xcxc,test7,
h,op,8,gb,eretet,test8,
i,qr,8,df,hjjh,test9,
```

**Python script written for this:**

```
import csv
import time
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('file1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
#print(columns[2])

b=(columns[2])
for x in b[:]:
    time.sleep(1)
    print x
```

**Output of above script:**

```
MacBook-Pro:test_usr$ python csv_file.py 
1
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
8
MacBook-Pro:test_usr$
```

I am able to do the steps 1 and 2.

Please guide me on doing Step-3. That is how to search for text/string in csv file and if present how to extract only specific column values to a new csv file?

**Output file should look like:**

```
a,ab
b,cd
c,ef
d,gh
e,ij
f,kl
g,mn
h,op
i,qr
```

Note : Search string will be from another csv file. Please don't suggest the direct answer for printing values of column 1 and 2 directly.

**FINAL CODE is looks this:**

```
import csv
import time
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('file1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
            b=(columns[2])

            for x in b[:]:
                with open('file2.csv') as f, open('file3.csv', 'a') as g:
                    reader = csv.reader(f)
                    #next(reader, None) # discard the header
                    writer = csv.writer(g)
                    for row in reader:
                        if row[2] == x:
                            writer.writerow(row[:2])
```

file1.csv:

```
Country,Location,number,letter,name,pup-name,null
a,ab,1,qw,abcd,test1,3
b,cd,1,df,efgh,test2,4
c,ef,2,er,fgh,test3,5
d,gh,3,sd,sds,test4,
e,ij,5,we,sdrt,test5,
f,kl,6,sc,asdf,test6,
g,mn,7,df,xcxc,test7,
h,op,8,gb,eretet,test8,
i,qr,8,df,hjjh,test9,
```

file2.csv:

```
count,name,number,Type,status,Config Version,,IP1,port
1,bob,1,TRAFFIC,end,1.2,,1.1.1.1,1
2,john,1,TRAFFIC,end,2.1,,1.1.1.2,2
4,foo,2,TRAFFIC,end,1.1,,1.1.1.3,3
5.333333333,test,3,TRAFFIC,end,3.1,,1.1.1.4,4
6.833333333,raa,5,TRAFFIC,end,5.1,,1.1.1.5,5
8.333333333,kaa,6,TRAFFIC,end,7.1,,1.1.1.6,6
9.833333333,thaa,7,TRAFFIC,end,9.1,,1.1.1.7,7
11.33333333,paa,8,TRAFFIC,end,11.1,,1.1.1.8,8
12.83333333,maa,8,TRAFFIC,end,13.1,,1.1.1.9,9
```

If I run the above script, output of file3.csv:

```
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
1,bob
2,john
.
.
.

Its goes like this in loop
```

But output should be like this:

```
count,name
1,bob,
2,john,
4,foo,
5.333333333,test,
6.833333333,raa,
8.333333333,kaa,
9.833333333,thaa,
11.33333333,paa,
12.83333333,maa,
```

Comment: "Take the value of index 0, " what index? What is the data you want to "match" on? The data form the third column? E.g. everywhere column 3 == '2', write the corresponding columns 1 and 2 to another file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited my question. Basically I want to take input ( a number or string) from another file. If that presents in column 3 of 'file1' and then want to extract the values of column 1,2 to a new csv file. I am really sorry for the confusing question/english.

Comment: So you don't want a header in your output file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need to have header also. if column 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 already present in that new file, column 1, 2 of file should get append as column 6,7 with header.

Comment: How would columns `1,2,3,4,5` be already present in a *new file*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just I want append to a existing file. I think we can tell to append by giving the column number 'x'. let me try this.

Comment: That's a whole other story! Nowhere near as straightforward as creating a new file. In fact, the easiest way will be to create a new file anyway, combining the two in memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144337/discussion-between-rcubefather-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I use "    with open('file2.csv') as f, open('file3.csv', 'a') as g:" I am able to get all values. but its with multiple times.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am suspecting looping issue in this script. It looping over again and again. I am unable to figureout what is causing. Could you please help on this.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is causing your troubles - you haven't provided any reproducible examples of the behavior, and when I test the code in the answer I provided, it works exactly as you would expect. Looking at your final code above, I have no idea why you made the modifications you have, but yes, the problem seems to be that you are looping too much. Why you've nested my solution inside a for-loop I cannot tell.

Comment: So, one thing is that the solutio I posted should be *all you need*. All that setup with `columns[i].append(v)` and `columns = defaultdict(list)` is unnecessary, and I suspect it is leading you astray. The whole point of my solution is that you don't need to group by columns, you can *do your operation row by row*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your approach. You can achieve your goal simply by iterating over the CSV file, without creating intermediate `dict`s and `list`s..., and since you want to work with specific columns, you'll make your life easier and your code more readable by using `DictReader` and `DictWriter`

```
import csv
import time

search_string = "whatever"

with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as f, open('file2.csv', 'wb') as g:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    c1, c2, c3, *_ = reader.fieldnames
    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, fieldnames=(c1, c2))
    for row in reader:
        if row[c3] == search_string:
            writer.writerow({c1:row[c1], c2:row[c2]})
```

Keep in mind that `csv` module will always return *strings*. You have to handle data-type conversions yourself, if you need them (I've left that out form above).

If you don't want to use `DictReader`/`DictWriter`, I suppose it is a little more verbose, and don't want a header in your output file:

```
with open('file1.csv') as f, open('file2.csv', 'w') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None) # discard the header
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == search_string:
            writer.writerow(row[:2])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answer. Now I am able to extract and write into a new file. Could you please guide me on following things? 1. How to get data from csv file in loop in this script, without hardcoding? 2. How to append as last two columns (With header) in new csv file if some column already present?

Comment: @rcubefather I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you edit your question and clarify what exactly you need the outputfile to look like? And what do you mean "hardcoded"?  The above script only things hardcoded are the filenames and the `search_str`, but you said that would come form another file...

Comment: sorry again for confusing... :) Thanks...got your idea. Let me try

Comment: I am getting "ValueError: too many values to unpack" error when I run first script

Comment: If I run the second script, its prints only last two rows values

Comment: @rcubefather with regards the to first script, that is likely because your csv is not well behaved and omits columns. As for the second script, it works fine for me, when I test it with the example you gave above... What are you using for `search_string`?

Comment: I have updated my question with latest code that I am using now. Its there under "FINAL CODE is looks this:"... Could you please check this.... Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I am getting  "   c1, c2, c3, *_ = reader.fieldnames
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax " error. Its shows error mark in *_

Comment: @rcubefather yes, that syntax only works in Python 3.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this with python 2.7? Else can you please help me get work with second part of your code. I mean without using "DictReader/DictWriter"

Comment: @rcubefather I provided **two equivalent solutions**.  Just use the other one. I already told you **I cannot help you because you haven't provided any reproducible examples of the behavior, and when I test the code in the answer I provided, it works exactly as you would expect and want given the inputs you have provided**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144436/discussion-between-rcubefather-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 2):

> That is how to search for text/string in csv file and if present how
>   to extract only specific column values to a new csv file?

This is two questions.

First question: to search for text in a file, the simplest answer would be to read the file text into memory and look for the text. If you want to look for the text in a specific column of the csv you're reading in, you can use a DictReader to make life easy:

```
for row in reader:
  if search_target in row[header]:
    # found it!
```

Second question:
One way to write specific columns to a new csv would be as follows:

```
keys = ["Country", "Location"]
new_rows = [{key: row[key] for key in keys} for row in reader]
writer = csv.DictWriter(somefile, keys)
writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help to understand better. Reading two csv files and matching the row indexs values are same or not, If same, writing to another csv.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import time
import os

output_dir = "D:\Laneending\data-ars540"
file1 = "3rd_test_rec_road_width_changing_scenarios_250_inference.csv"
file2 = "df_5_signals_1597515776730734.csv"

ars540 = os.path.join(output_dir, file1)
veh_dyn = os.path.join(output_dir, file2)

file3 = "df_5_signals_1597515776730734_processed.csv"
output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, file3)

with open(ars540, 'r') as f1, open(veh_dyn, 'r') as f2, \
        open(output_file, 'w+', newline='') as f3:
    f1_reader = csv.reader(f1)
    f2_reader = csv.reader(f2)
    header_f1 = []
    header_f1 = next(f1_reader) # reading the next line after header of csv file.

    header_f2 = []
    header_f2 = next(f2_reader) # reading the next line after header of csv file.
    count = 0
    writer = csv.writer(f3) #preparing the file f3 for writing the file.

    writer.writerow(["Timestamp", "no of detections", "velocity", "yawrate" , "afdr"])

    for row_f1 in f1_reader: # looking each row from csv file f1
        for row_f2 in f2_reader: # looking for each row from csv file f2
            if row_f1[1] == row_f2[0]: #checking the condition; worse case Time complexity o(n2)
                # print(row_f2)
                print(count)
                writer = csv.writer(f3)
                writer.writerows([row_f2])
                count +=1
                break
```