# How to search for a specific column value in csv file, if present , write first two column values to a new csv file with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

file1.csv:

```
Country,Location,number,letter,name,pup-name,null
a,ab,1,qw,abcd,test1,3
b,cd,1,df,efgh,test2,4
c,ef,2,er,fgh,test3,5
d,gh,3,sd,sds,test4,
e,ij,DDDD,we,sdrt,test5,
f,kl,6,sc,asdf,test6,
g,mn,7,df,xcxc,test7,
h,op,8,gb,eretet,test8,
i,qr,8,df,hjjh,test9,
```

I want to search for string/number in 3rd column of above csv file. And if present, write the 'first two column values' to another file.

For example:

```
In 3rd column, number 6 is present --- > Then I want write 'f','kl' into a new csv file (with headers) 
In 3rd column, string DDDD is present ---> Then I want to write 'e','ij' into a new csv file.
```

Please guide me how we can do this with Python?

I am trying with below code:

```
import csv
import time

search_string = "1"

with open('file1.csv') as f, open('file3.csv', 'w') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None) # discard the header
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == search_string:
            writer.writerow(row[:2])
```

But its printing only last two row values.

Comment: if your `search_string = "1"`. then if you are using this to search in 3rd column, then matching rows only two are found.
Are you expecting different thing?
I think if you share your current output and expected output, then people can guide you.
One suggestion is, you can do this kind of dataframe parsing very easily using pandas. try ---> `import pandas as pd; data = pd.read_csv("file1.csv") ` and do further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a 'text' or 'number' in a csv file with Python AND if exists print only first and second column values to a new csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986126/how-to-search-for-a-text-or-number-in-a-csv-file-with-python-and-if-exists-p)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your code:

- The third column of the row in `row[2]`, you are right.
- The first two columns are `row[0:2]` or `row[:2]`, you are right.

If I simulate the reading, like this:

```
import io
import csv

data = """Country,Location,number,letter,name,pup-name,null
a,ab,1,qw,abcd,test1,3
b,cd,1,df,efgh,test2,4
c,ef,2,er,fgh,test3,5
d,gh,3,sd,sds,test4,
e,ij,DDDD,we,sdrt,test5,
f,kl,6,sc,asdf,test6,
g,mn,7,df,xcxc,test7,
h,op,8,gb,eretet,test8,
i,qr,8,df,hjjh,test9,
"""

with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)  # discard the header
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == "1":
            print(row[:2])
```

It prints:

```
['a', 'ab']
['b', 'cd']
```

Change the value of *search_string*…

Comment: Yes, this was the [answer I gave to the same question that was asked before by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986126/how-to-search-for-a-text-or-number-in-a-csv-file-with-python-and-if-exists-p/43986604?noredirect=1#comment75020635_43986604).

Comment: So, let's consider it is a duplicate…