# How to find key from given value using machine learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, key-value, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a CSV file with first row as header & after that each row has set of values for each column. Each row in the CSV correspond to some field in the DB. user has to manually map the header attributes to Business fields (or DB fields).

I want to use machine learning to avoid this manual mapping. Ideally from the given value I want to detect the corresponding key/column.

Is any services (preferably Azure) to machine learn from set of key-value pairs. When a value is provided then it should detect the keys?   Please note this does not involve any OCR, my data is in CSV form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this need a machine learning algorithm to do it but a search algorithm. Based on my understanding, you have a csv document which contains keys on a column and values after that column, what you want to do is given a value then find the key.

There is a very similar question and also good solution to do it by python script.
[How to search for a 'text' or 'number' in a csv file with Python AND if exists print only first and second column values to a new csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986126/how-to-search-for-a-text-or-number-in-a-csv-file-with-python-and-if-exists-p)

Comment: There is manual way to do mapping of column to set of values. I want ML to learn from set of values & detect this mapping automatically. You can consider that once it is trained  no need to provide any header in the CSV/input. For the given value/or set of values it should detect that most likely input value(s) are for some key X. 
Hope I am clear now.